# If an array is sorted from 0 to i-1, and a[i-1] is lower than a[i], why can't Dafny prove the array is sorted from 0 to i?

Tags: dafny

Consider the following code:

```
predicate sorted(a:array<int>, min:int, max:int)
    requires a != null
    requires 0 <= min <= max <= a.Length 
    reads a
{
    forall i,j | min <= i < j < max :: a[i] <= a[j] 
}

method test(a:array<int>,i:int)
    requires a!=null 
    requires a.Length>i
    requires i>0
    requires sorted(a,0,i-1)
    requires a[i-1]<a[i]
    ensures sorted(a,0,i)
{
    
}
```

The method `test` requires that the array `a` is sorted from 0 to `i-1`, and that `a[i-1] < a[i]`. But Dafny reports an error with the post condition that `a` is sorted from 0 to `i`. Isn't this obvious? Why can't Dafny prove it?

Answer (score 0):

The reason that Dafny cannot prove it is because it is false. We can use `test` to prove false as follows:

```
method using_test_proves_false()
{
  var a := new int[3];
  a[0] := 8;
  a[1] := 7;
  a[2] := 9;
  assert sorted(a, 0, 1);
  assert a[0] > a[1];
  assert !sorted(a, 0, 2);
  assert a[1] < a[2];
  test(a, 2);
  assert sorted(a, 0, 2);
  assert false;
}
```

The basic problem is that there is an off-by-one error on `i` in the `test` requirements. I think you might have meant to say `a[i-2] < a[i-1]`?

---

Also, based on your requirement `a != null`, it looks like you might be using a fairly old version of Dafny. I recommend upgrading to a recent version.

Comment: Thank you very much. Another question is how to define a not null array in the recent version,i think my dafny version is relatest.To be honest,learning from the tutorial of rise4fun, i am still confused about dafny.

Comment: In recent Dafny, arrays are non-null by default. If you want it to be nullable, you can use `array?<int>` in recent Dafny.